# Is there a generic update notification/pub sub system for GTK?

Tags: python, user-interface, architecture, gtk, pygtk

I'm building a PyGTK application with several widgets that when changed, need to **notify other widgets about the change**. I would like to avoid code like this:

```
def on_entry_color_updated(self, widget):
    self.paint_tools_panel.current_color_pane.update_color()
    self.main_window.status_bar.update_color()
    self.current_tool.get_brush().update_color()
```

And do something like this instead:

```
def on_entry_color_updated(self, widget):
    self.update_notify('color-changed')
```

The status bar, current color pane and current tool would subscribe to that notification event and act accordingly. From what I can tell, the GObject signaling mechanism only allows me to register a callback on a particular widget, so each object that wants to receive a notification has to be aware of that widget.

**Does GTK provide such a system or should I build it myself?** Developers of Shotwell, a photo organization application for GNOME, had to build their own signaling mechanism, if I understand their [design doc](http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/wiki/ShotwellArchDataStructures) correctly. Searching here on SO didn't turn out any definitive answers.

### Edit:

Clarification why I think GObject signaling is not what I need (or just a part of what I need). With GObject, I need to explicitly connect an object to another object, like so:

```
emitter.connect('custom-event', receiver.event_handler)
```

So in my application, I would have to do this:

```
class ColorPane(gtk.Something):
    def __init__(self, application):
        # init stuff goes here...

        application.color_pallette.connect('color-changed', self.update_color)

    def update_color(self, widget):
        """Show the new color."""
        pass

class StatusBar(gtk.Something):
    def __init__(self, application):
        # init stuff goes here...

        application.color_pallette.connect('color-changed', self.update_color)

    def update_color(self, widget):
        """Show the new color name."""
        pass

class Brush(gtk.Something):
    def __init__(self, application):
        # init stuff goes here...

        application.color_pallette.connect('color-changed', self.update_color)

    def update_color(self, widget):
        """Draw with new color."""
        pass
```

In other words, I have to pass the application object or some other object that knows about the color_pallete to other objects in my application so that they connect to color_pallette signals. This is the kind of coupling that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you could create a custom subclass of `GObject`, which provides some [custom signals](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/subclassing-gobject/sub-classing-gobject-in-python.htm#d0e570). The following example is a slightly adapted version of the one given in the linked article:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gobject

class Car(gobject.GObject):

    __gsignals__ = {
        'engine-started': (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, ()),
        'engine-stopped': (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, ()),
    }

    def __init__(self):
        gobject.GObject.__init__(self)
        self._state = 0

    def start(self):
        if not self._state:
            self._state = 1
            self.emit('engine-started')

    def stop(self):
        if self._state:
            self._state = 0
            self.emit('engine-stopped')


gobject.type_register(Car)

def kill_switch(c):
    def callback(*unused, **ignored):
        c.stop()
    return callback

def on_start(*unused, **ignored):
    print "Started..."

def on_stop(*unused, **ignored):
    print "Stopped..."

some_car = Car()
some_car.connect('engine-started', on_start)
some_car.connect('engine-started', kill_switch(some_car))
some_car.connect('engine-stopped', on_stop)
some_car.start()
```

Another approach would be to take advantage of one of the many event/signalling packages already on PyPI, for example:

- [Zope Event](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.event)
- [Louie](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Louie)
- [PyDispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/)
- [Darts Events](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/darts.util.events)
- [Trellis](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Trellis)

Answer (score 1):

GObjects don't have to be widgets. For example, your application class can be a GObject which defines signals that other widgets connect to.

Also, I don't think you understood the Shotwell design document correctly. It looks to me like their signalling system is 100% GObject signalling system, just with particular guarantees about the order in which signals are handled. As they say in their design document, such things are possible in plain GObject, but Vala makes it easier to code it their way.

Comment: I think GObject signaling is not suitable for my purposes becase it requires me to connect two objects explicitly. I have updated my question to clarify.